# Zencoder encoding speed preset

Tags: encoding, preset, zencoder

On the `Zencoder` site it's said that there are 1-5 values for the transcoding speed:

> A target transcoding speed. 
>        Slower transcoding allows for more advanced file compression,
>        while faster transcoding is possible by skipping some advanced compression features. 
>        Valid values are 1-5.

And on the `ffmpeg`site current presets are:

`ultrafast`, `superfast`, `veryfast`, `faster`, `fast`, `medium`, `slow`, `slower`, `veryslow` and `placebo`

So can me someone tell me please, which value i have to choose if i want as encoding speed 'slow'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Zencoder Support team it is:

1:`Slower`

2:`Slow`

3:`Medium`

4:`Fast`

5:`Faster`